# fstat - total file descriptor count on freebsd system?

Tags: freebsd, file-descriptor, fstat

How to get the current count of file descriptors in the system?

I know how to get the maximum.

```
% sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 8232
```

Ref:

http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Comment: Any one know about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `kern.openfiles`?

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sysctl -ad | grep 'kern.*files:'
kern.maxfiles: Maximum number of files
kern.openfiles: System-wide number of open files
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Answer (score -3):

cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr

Three columns are `total file descriptors allocated since boot`, `free allocated file descriptors`, `maximum open file descriptors`.

Additional info [here](http://www.netadmintools.com/art295.html).